# Azure Automation - How to load Azure Storage assembly into run book

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

Using the code here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919145.aspx

I am trying to break the leases on blobs created by SQL backup to URL so that I can then remove old blobs using remove-azurestorageblob

This works like a dream on-premises but I would like to run it in Azure Automation

I need to load the storage assembly but I cannot seem to get it.

I looked at this answer

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/45251bdb-bb20-488c-a428-3ee1094fd568/referencing-microsoftwindowsazurestoragedll-and-creating-cloud-blob-client-using?forum=azureautomation

and tried to use the C:\modules folder to load

```
$storageAssemblyPath = "C:\Modules\Global\Azure\Compute\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll"
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($storageAssemblyPath)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($bytes)
```

I wrote a runbook to search for the dll

```
workflow robs
{
Inlinescript{
cd /
pwd

get-childitem *WindowsAzure.Storage.dll -recurse
}
}
```

and tried to load using the paths returned which are in c:\modules\global but always get the error could not find assembly

Answer (score 0):

strangely it has now worked once I had dropped and recreated the run book as it was not saving my changes.

So there is something weird going on with the new azure portal azure automation authoring pane which was not saving my changes correctly I believe and therefore constantly giving me the error